# Would it be possible to buy a Stack Overflow T-shirt?

Tags: discussion, 10m-questions-milestone

Would it be possible to sell SO t-shirts again for the short period of celebration time?

Given that you are apparently going to [print](https://stackoverflow.com/10m) some and I am definitely not gonna be one of the 50 lucky ones I was wondering whether you could print some more for a certain fee.

Comment: This is [explained on Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/137580): it's not that they can't print more shirts, it's that __selling__ tangible goods is an administrative burden they don't want to carry.

Comment: Why cant you just get the logo and have a shirt company print it out?

Comment: [We're hiring...](http://stackexchange.com/work-here)

Comment: @NormalHuman Thanks for the context but my question basically is exactly whether they want to take that burden for a batch/short period of time.

Comment: @JonH Would SO be ok with that?

Comment: @DavidRobinson Unfortunately, no junior developers I guess ...

Comment: Likely just as easy for us to design and print a shirt with the SO logo than it is to ask them to produce them for us

Comment: "Definitely not"?  C'mon, get optimistic about it, at least.

Comment: @inf Selling for a short period of time entails being liable for assorted taxes that _year_.

Comment: I WANTS SOME SWAG!

Comment: I've got a size L stackoverflow tshirt originally mailed to me from Jeff Atwood. It could probably go for thousands of dollars based on what I'm seeing...

Comment: I think not selling them makes the shirts much more valuable to those who are given then, it makes it more significant. Selling them could lead people to attach monetary value to them, instead of sentimental value. (However, as someone who owns several, I am admittedly biased.)

Comment: @JeremyBanks I would totally understand that argument but from what I gathered in the past (and the referenced link) I am not sure whether that is the reason.

Comment: I must admit getting an "official" SO t-shirt seems way more appealing to me now than the Apple Watch did when it was announced. Or perhaps even the larger iPhone.

Comment: @JeremyBanks: Yeah, maybe I should try to put my second or third one on eBay or so :-)

Answer (score -8):

Right now, you cannot buy, but you can get a SO t-shirt by participating a special event running in Meta.

[10 Million Questions - Let's Share Some Stories That the Number Doesn't Convey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303045/10-million-questions-lets-share-some-stories-that-the-number-doesnt-convey)

> Why yes. The good news is, this isn't a contest, **everyone** that shares something here will receive:
>
> - 1 Stack Overflow T shirt (Men's or Women's)
> - ...

Comment: I know what I can do right now but that's not my question.

Comment: Rather than make up a story about how an SO question changed my life in exchange for a shirt, I'd prefer to just give SO money.

Comment: @ObliviousSage: Hey, it did change your life enough that you want to wear a shirt with their logo. So what happened? We're curious!

Comment: @Bergi Stack Overflow, as a general tool, has been *amazingly* helpful. No one Stack Overflow question, on the other hand, has been life-changing.